# Where to Stick RemoveBackEntry(From Cimbalino Toolkit)?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, cimbalino

I have right now a windows phone 8 application that uses cimbalino Toolkit navigation service in my View Model.

I have a MainPage and a AddItemPage. When a user add and item and hits the save button, I have it go back to the MainPage.

Now I want to remove the AddItemPage from the back stack. Yet I have no clue where to put "RemoveBackEntry".

Answer (score 0):

`RemoveBackEntry` should be in the `MainPage.OnNavigatedTo`. But this method is called every time MainPage is shown, so you have to check if last entry on the BackStack is really the page you should remove (e.g. by passing some parameter in the query string (which will be available in OnNavigatedTo) or by examining the entries in the BackStack).

Much better approach would be to call `NavigationService.GoBack()` after the save on the `AddItemPage`.

Comment: Well right now I on save the Navigate from Cimbalino to go back to the MainPage, why would it be better to use GoBack?

Comment: @chobo2 because that's what you want to do - return to the previous page, so why use Navigate, when there's better logical action for it? Cimbalino's INavigationService *has* `GoBack method.

Comment: Will the GoBack RemoveBackEntry of the AddItemPage?

Comment: @chobo2 Yes (why not test it)?